# Having a input text appear when chosen option in a double drop down select option

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Say I want to create a double drop down select options where the second drop down list changes according to which the first drop down option is selected. I've already figured out how to do this. BUT one of my first drop option is "Others" and I want an input textbox to appear if I select "others" in the first dropdown list instead of having a second drop down option list. So far, I've been able to get the input textbox to appear, but the second drop down option list also appears (as undefined). How do I make the second drop down option list disappear?? Also, if one of the options in the first dropdown list doesn't need or have a second drop down option list, how do I code this?

This is an example of my script (I only changed the names of the categories):

```
    <form name="search" method="get">
        <select name="cat" id="cat" size="1" onChange="redirect(this.options.selectedIndex)">
            <option selected disabled>Category</option>          
            <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
            <option value="music">Music</option>
            <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
            <option value="book">Book</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>

        <input type='text' id="other" class="hidden" />

        <select name="cat2" size="1">
            <option selected disabled>Sub-category</option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" name="Search" value="Search" onClick="go()" /        
    </form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$('#cat').change(function(){
var selected_item = $(this).val()

if(selected_item == "other"){
    $('#other').val("").removeClass('hidden');
}else{
    $('#other').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
}
});

var groups=document.search.cat.options.length
var group=new Array(groups)
for (i=0; i<groups; i++)
group[i]=new Array()

group[0][0]=0

group[1][0]=new Option("Moodle")
group[1][1]=new Option("Ultranet")
group[1][2]=new Option("Private School")

group[2][0]=new Option("Gmail")
group[2][1]=new Option("Windows Live")
group[2][2]=new Option("Office 365")

group[3][0]=0 //has no second dropdown option, how do I make it disappear?

group[4][0]=new Option("Kamar")
group[4][1]=new Option("Musac")

group[5][0]=new Option("Windows")
group[5][1]=new Option("Mac")
group[5][2]=new Option("Novell")
group[5][3]=new Option("Linux")

group[6][0]=new Option("Ruckus Wireless")
group[6][1]=new Option("Aerohive Networks")
group[6][2]=new Option("Aruba Networks")

group[7][0]=new Option("Pre-Trial")
group[7][1]=new Option("Implementation")
group[7][2]=new Option("Full Trial")

group[8][0]=0 //The 'others', I don't know what to put here to make this disappear

var temp=document.search.cat2

function redirect(x){
for (m=temp.options.length-1;m>0;m--)
temp.options[m]=null
for (i=0;i<group[x].length;i++){
temp.options[i]=new Option(group[x][i].text,group[x][i].value)
}
temp.options[0].selected=true
}

function go(){
location=temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value
}
```

Comment: Just an optional kind advice, consider using brackets even when they are not mandatory and indentations, it will not only improve our response quality, but it will help you see the problems easier. Also the line terminator ";" is optional but it is easier to read a block of code that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 2 new lines to the .change function, from:

```
$('#cat').change(function(){
var selected_item = $(this).val()

if(selected_item == "other"){
    $('#other').val("").removeClass('hidden');
}else{
    $('#other').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
}
});
```

Change it to

```
$('#cat').change(function(){
var selected_item = $(this).val()

if(selected_item == "other"){
    $('#other').val("").removeClass('hidden');
    $("select[name=cat2]").addClass('hidden');
}else{
    $('#other').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
    $("select[name=cat2]").removeClass('hidden');
}
});
```

So when you remove hidden class from the input you have to add it to the select with name "cat2", and vice-versa. Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks so much, it worked. Do you know how to remove one of the second drop down option list when the first one is selected?

Comment: To remove options from second drop down list try $("select[name=cat2] option[value=?]").remove(); but replace the question mark(?) with the value of the option that needs to be removed.